# Using Apache HTTPClient to submit tricky form data

Tags: java, apache

Here's my code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.webcitation.org/comb.php");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(??, ??));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fromform", "2"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "example@example.com"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            String line = "";
            while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

And here's the HTML code of the form I'm trying to mimic: http://www.webcitation.org/69Qsz3Tdn

I'm trying to submit the URLs `http://video.google.com/?hl=en&tab=wv`, `http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=wl`, etc. to the PHP file through Java and read the response. Since there are no `name`s for the `href`s, I'm stumped. Also the checkboxes have no `value`s, so I can't check whether they are checked or not.

Thanks for any assistance!!

Comment: What do you mean? The hrefs wouldn't be submitted at all, they're just that--links. I'd assume there's something on the server side that maps the URLs to the checkbox names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You'll not get the expected response.**

The response from comb.php depends on a html form.

in your html form values ​​are not specified. So I can not see how comb.php test the checkboxes.

```
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="cachingurl0"/></td>
 <td><a href="http://video.google.com/?hl=en&tab=wv">http://video.google.com/?hl=en&tab=wv</a></td>
```

**with value :**

```
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="cachingurl0" value="checked" /></td>
```

1.) You also need a java App with a GUI like form (example a Swing-form App). There you can check or uncheck the needed checkboxes.

2.) You have to pass appropriate variables to comb.php. For Example:

```
if (myCheckB0.checked) { nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cachingurl0", "checked"));}
if (myCheckB5.checked) { nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cachingurl5", "checked"));
```